# Condition not working properly inside getView in BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have a `ListView` in my application to show list of records. I have a `Button` and some `RadioButton` and they need to be visible or invisible based on some condition. When the list gets scrolled, the last view becomes a duplicate and the condition does not work properly. What is happening and how do I fix it?

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.approval_list, null);

        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Initialization of ListView Components 
        //holder.indivListvLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.indRevLayout);
         holder.tv_com_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_com_title);
         holder.tv_designation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_designation);
         holder.et_commnents = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_commnents);
         holder.rb_rev = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rb_rev);
         holder.rb_rej = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rb_rej);
         holder.btn_modify = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_modify);
                        //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>End Initialization

                        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Make visible radio button according to user_group code
         //List User Group Code
         String user_group_code = mDisplayedValues.get(position).user_group_code;
         //Log.e("User Group code from list", user_group_code);
         if("RO".equals(user_group_code)){
            holder.rb_app_recom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }else if("RM".equals(user_group_code)){
            holder.rb_app_recom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }else("BDM".equals(user_group_code)){
            holder.rb_app_recom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.rb_rej_req.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }

                        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Selection of radio button according to flag
         //Getting flag value
         String approve_flag = mDisplayedValues.get(position).approve_flg;

         if(approve_flag.equals("A")){
            holder.rb_approved.setChecked(true);
         }else (approve_flag.equals("R")){
            holder.rb_rev.setChecked(true);
         }
         //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>End selecting radio button

                        //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Make radio button click able
         //String user_group_code2 = user_session_sp.getString("user_group_code", " ");
         if(user_group_code2.equals(mDisplayedValues.get(position).user_group_code)){
            holder.rb_approved.setClickable(true);
            holder.rb_rev.setClickable(true);
         }else{
            holder.rb_approved.setClickable(false);
            holder.rb_rev.setClickable(false);
         }
         //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>End selecting radio button clekcable Setting
         convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tv_com_title.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).groucode +" "+ mDisplayedValues.get(position).comments_by+" "+ mDisplayedValues.get(position).designation);
    holder.tv_designation.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).user_group_code);
    holder.et_commnents.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).comments);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Set Visibility outside if-else loop will solve your problem.

Comment: In ListView view render every time you scroll your view. here you have used view-holder pattern so it will reuse same view hence no visibility change.

Comment: 'if-else' is it a loop? @Dhaval Patel

Comment: Take a look>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works

Comment: if view-holder reuse  same view it that means view will not replace with new data? Is that means after scrolling list will show same data?

Comment: I red it from .. http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296 .

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

the problem was your condition statements were executing for first item only (initialization time when convertedview is `null`) otherwise it'll not be executed.

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.approval_list, null);

                //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Initialization of ListView Components 
                //holder.indivListvLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.indRevLayout);
                holder.tv_com_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_com_title);
                holder.tv_designation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_designation);
                holder.et_commnents = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_commnents);
                holder.rb_rev = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rb_rev);
                holder.rb_rej = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rb_rej);
                holder.btn_modify = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_modify);
                //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>End Initialization

                //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>End selecting radio button clekcable Setting
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Make visible radio button according to user_group code
                //List User Group Code
                String user_group_code = mDisplayedValues.get(position).user_group_code;
                //Log.e("User Group code from list", user_group_code);
                if("RO".equals(user_group_code)){
                    holder.rb_app_recom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else if("RM".equals(user_group_code)){
                    holder.rb_app_recom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else("BDM".equals(user_group_code)){
                    holder.rb_app_recom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.rb_rej_req.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Selection of radio button according to flag
                //Getting flag value
                String approve_flag = mDisplayedValues.get(position).approve_flg;

                if(approve_flag.equals("A")){
                    holder.rb_approved.setChecked(true);
                }else (approve_flag.equals("R")){
                    holder.rb_rev.setChecked(true);
                }
                //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>End selecting radio button

                //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Make radio button click able
                //String user_group_code2 = user_session_sp.getString("user_group_code", " ");
                if(user_group_code2.equals(mDisplayedValues.get(position).user_group_code)){
                    holder.rb_approved.setClickable(true);
                    holder.rb_rev.setClickable(true);
                }else{
                    holder.rb_approved.setClickable(false);
                    holder.rb_rev.setClickable(false);
                }

            holder.tv_com_title.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).groucode +" "+ mDisplayedValues.get(position).comments_by+" "+ mDisplayedValues.get(position).designation);
            holder.tv_designation.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).user_group_code);
            holder.et_commnents.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).comments);

          return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: I have apply all condition outside if (convertView == null) {convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }. But no change I found.

Comment: yeah, then only those conditions executes for each row

Comment: see your code in question currently all conditions are inside `if(convertedView == null){}` block

Comment: I said ............ I have applied all condition outside of  if(convertedView == null){} first time. Then when it show problem then I put it inside. So inside and outside both not working..

Comment: debug and see whether you are getting correct data from `mDisplayedValues` otherwise everything is good

Comment: There is no problem at all............... but some times when scroll it not work properly ..........this is the problem...

Comment: There is no Error............    I print this log like this. .0 position view some time from if and some time form else when scroll . Whay i dont know ...Log.e("EEEEEEEEEE", "from if.. "+position);
      convertView.setTag(holder);
           } else {
            Log.e("EEEEEEEEEE", "from else.."+position);
               holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
           }

Answer (score 0):

While using viewholder pattern you have to handle every situation:

```
if(approve_flag.equals("A")){
   holder.rb_approved.setChecked(true);
else {
   holder.rb_approved.setChecked(false);
}
if (approve_flag.equals("R")){
   holder.rb_rev.setChecked(true);
}
else {
   holder.rb_rev.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between if(condition){}else{} if(condition){}else{} and if(condition){}else if(condition)(condition){}else{}

Answer (score 0):

In `ViewHolder` pattern, only `if` statement causes **unexpected results**

So better use, `if` along with `else`

**Example:**

```
if(condition){
   //special execution
}else{
   //default execution
}
```